# API request limit work around

Tags: database, api, react-native

I'm building a react native app and want to pull information from an API that has a 10 requests/minute limit. This will be okay with just a couple of users but I'm concerned that this won't scale. For example if 30 users are using the app at once then there will be 30 API requests and 20 users won't get the data. What is the typical solution to this? Should I create a database that requests from the API every minute then stores the data short term and then my users get their data from my database? Is that overkill? I'm new and just trying to understand. Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: scale up your API server to make it more responsible. (for example, use cache)

Comment: can you explain? I am initially requesting from an API that isn't mine btw

Answer (score 1):

From OP's request,

Yes, you should pull information from API Server (which is not yours) every several seconds, to not exceed its limit (for example, 10 requests / per minute).

And then you can:

1. Store them into database. Or which would be better if data size not too big: Store them in memory.
2. Repopulate your pulling server as a delegate API server.

So every react native APP can just pull from your new delegation server, with much larger request limits.